# UTF8 encoded cstring byte lenght

Tags: c++, utf-8, c-strings

Can I use `std::strlen()` on null terminated UTF8 string and expect it to work? That is count ***the string lenght in bytes*** not in glyphs/codepoints?
Or does the UTF8 multi byte codepoints just break `strlen()` in this case?

I'm bit paranoid about it and I'm currently doing following with utf8cpp library:

```
size_t utf8bytelen(const char * utf8str) {
    const char * itr = utf8str;
    while(*itr && utf8::unchecked::next(itr));
    return std::distance(utf8str, itr);
}
```

Comment: expect it to work... what were the results when you tried?

Comment: I did get the byte lenght, but if any utf-8 multibyte codepoints have zero bytes in them it would obiviusly break. I asked this question since there where no such question yet, and I didn't have clear answer to it.

Comment: Utf-8 doesn't contain null bytes (other than when you encode the null character itself)

Comment: In UTF-8 all code points <= 127 stand for themselves and those byte values are not used for any other purpose. So you should be fine.

Comment: @AlanBirtles good, I can now drop this hack finally.. :)